# How to override $page_top variable?

Tags: theming

I am new to drupal 7 theming. I see that there is a variable called `$page_top`  in `html.tpl.php` file, which contains HTML markup for the header section of the body. I want to override this and print my markup. How can I do that in `template.php` file, or is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use hook_preprocess_html() like this :

`function hook_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  $vars['page']['page_top'][] = array('foo' => array('#markup' => 'foo'));
  // Or other render array stuff
}`

Answer (score 1):

You override markup by using :

```
  function template_preprocess_field(&$vars){ 
    if($vars['element']['#field_name'] == 'field_event_geofield')
     {
          //kpr($vars); //Uncomment to output the $vars array.

           if(isset($vars['element']['#items']['0']['lat']) && isset($vars['element']['#items']['0']['lon'])) { $vars['items']['0']['#markup'] = 'View Map'; } return; } 
           }
```